# How do I handle the death of another node in Erlang?

Tags: erlang

I have two nodes that are connected to each other, where one of them is the server. The server would like to know if the client dies. I did something like this:

```
link(Client).
```

In the server process, and when I did that I receive a exception error: noconnection and then the server dies, when the client dies. I would just like to know if the client dies, I do not want the server do die, how do I handle the death message?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have two erlang nodes and want to take some actions in case if one node goes down (or network connection is lost) you possible want to use `erlang:monitor_node/2,3` functions:

```
(n1@myhost)1> erlang:monitor_node('n2@myhost', true).
true
```

then if `'n2@myhost'` node goes down your process will receive message:

```
(n1@myhost)2> flush().
Shell got {nodedown,n2@myhost}
```

(note, I did that from erlang shell, that is why I may call `flush/0` to see what is in the mailbox of the shell process)

If you interested in certain process, on the second node you may use `erlang:monitor/2`

```
(n1@myhost)3> Ref = erlang:monitor(process, {'n2@myhost', some_registered_name}).
#Ref<0.0.0.117>
```

from now you will receive a message if `some_registered_name` goes down and you can take an action.

Also you may be interested in how to write [distributed applications](http://learnyousomeerlang.com/distributed-otp-applications)

Answer (score 2):

To have unidirectional supervision, you should use [monitors](http://learnyousomeerlang.com/errors-and-processes#monitors). Then your server will receive a message if the client dies.

Comment: Or trap exits in the server process.